# Should the WP post editor B (bold) button be inserting a <b> tag instead of <strong> in HTML5?

Tags: tinymce, post-editor

Using WP 4.0. I thought that the html5 schema was supposed to be turned on by default. That would mean that clicking the B (Bold) button would generate a `<b>` tag, rather than a `<strong>` tag (which has a different semantic meaning). The same question goes for clicking the I button to get an `<i>` tag instead of `<em>`. How can I get the editor to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I came up with. So far it doesn't seem to have broken anything:

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'modify_formats');

function modify_formats($settings){
   $formats = array(
     'bold' => array('inline' => 'b'),
     'italic' => array('inline' => 'i')
    );
    $settings['formats'] = json_encode( $formats );
    return $settings;
}
```

One could easily have used  plus a class here, but given the changes in the spec under html5,  and  seem acceptable for most situations. (I don't think that the case to transform these from presentational to structural tags is terribly persuasive, but probably not worth arguing about at this point). Anyone who wants  and  should probably add the necessary buttons and apply them in the appropriate places.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by changing in TinyMCE Editor `formats` as:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  formats: {
    // Changes the default format for the bold button to produce a span with a bold class
    bold: { inline: 'b', classes: 'bold' }
  }
});
```

[Content formatting options
in TinyMCE Editor](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/)

If you are on WordPress then this article will be helpful for you https://tfrommen.de/using-custom-formats-in-tinymce/

Comment: Where the code has to be placed?

Comment: in javascript at footer

Comment: I put it in the footer (using Insert Headers and Footers plugin) but the script is not loaded in the admin area, it is just loaded in the public site. What is the proper way to load it in the admin area?

Comment: Please see this article https://mattwatson.codes/articles/custom-tinymce-editor-formatting-in-wordpress/

Comment: for wordpress use this https://tfrommen.de/using-custom-formats-in-tinymce/

Comment: Are you using WordPress?

Comment: Yes, I created the file `bolditalic.js` (with your code inside it) and put it in `wp-content\themes\mysite\js` folder. Then in `functions.php` file I wrote `function mysite_scripts() { wp_enqueue_script( 'mysite-bolditalic', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bolditalic.js', array('jquery') ); add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mysite_scripts' );` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please try this https://tfrommen.de/using-custom-formats-in-tinymce/

Comment: This seems very complicated, I added a new button bold with this easy command `QTags.addButton( 'bold', 'bold', '<b>', '</b>', '', '', '1' );`. Thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score -1):

The i and b tags are perfectly valid HTML(5).

Otherwise ( untested, only on output thus saved to DB as a b tag still ) :

```
function change_b_to_strong($content){
    str_replace('<b>', '<strong>', $content);
    str_replace('</b>', '</strong>', $content);
    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'change_b_to_strong' );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am only asking about having the bold button generate a <b> tag, and the I button an <i> tag. I don't want <strong> or <em> unless the semantics call for them.